# Running emulationstation from remote laptop

Tags: remote, retropie, putty, xming

I downloaded Retropie for my RPi and I'd like to configure and tweak emulationstation from my Windows laptop.

I tried connecting to the Pi with putty, but I can't run emulationstation. I get the message :

```
X is running. Please shut down X in order to mitigate problems with loosing keyboard input. For example, logout from LXDE.
```

I checked with ps axg and lxde doesn't seeem to be running, neither does X...

I also tried running it from Xming but it doesn't work (the previous message seems to indicate that emulationstation doesn't use X so I guess it's normal). I can run LXDE from it though.

So I don't know what to do...

Comment: Have you tried switching to runlevel 3?

Comment: You mean debian runlevel 3 (with telinit) ? I'm afraid I don't know enough about Linux to understand why and how it'd solve my problem. Could you be more precise please ? (run it from putty ? using Xming ? relations with the message ?)

Comment: Yes. I'm referring to that. just run `init 3` as root.

Comment: If the message advises **against X** , why did you start XMing ? I believe a lot of emulation cores will use HW acceleration or raw FB access - **they will not work over VNC/RDP/X forwarding** !!

Answer (score 2):

Do: `apt-get update && apt-get install xrdp`

Then Remote Desktop into the pi: 0.0.0.0:3389 (0.0.0.0 is the IP of the RPi)

Then you will see a desktop, but no icons or anything (Assuming you are running RetroPie and NOT Raspbian) just right click and select "Terminal Emulator" or Open Terminal and then type "emulationstation"

That *should* launch it in the RDP window for you.

I have not tried this, but it should work.

Comment: Hello and welcome. [0.0.0.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) is certainly not the IP of the Pi, at least not from any other different that's different from the Pi...

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is an example IP Address I could have said X.X.X.X but they both mean the same. Obviously 0.0.0.0 would not work it will most likely actually be 192.168.1.X